# Making a python package for PIP with some data_files

Tags: python, package, distutils, pip, data-files

I'm doing a project with this layout:

```
project/
    bin/
        my_bin.py
    CHANGES.txt
    docs/
    LICENSE.txt
    README.txt
    MANIFEST.in
    setup.py
    project/
        __init__.py
        some_thing.py
        default_data.json
        other_datas/
            default/
                other_default_datas.json
```

And the problem is that when I install this using pip, it puts the **"default_data.json"** and the **"other_datas"** folder not in the same place as the rest of the app.

How am I supposed to do to make them be in the same place?

They end up on **"/home/user/.virtualenvs/proj-env/project"**

instead of **"/home/user/.virtualenvs/proj-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/project"**

In the setup.py I'm doing it like this:

```
inside_dir = 'project'
data_folder= os.path.join(inside_dir,'other_datas')

data_files = [(inside_dir, [os.path.join(inside_dir,'default_data.json')])]
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(data_folder):
    data_files.append([dirpath, [os.path.join(dirpath, f) for f in filenames]])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From https://docs.python.org/3.4/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files:

> If *directory* is a relative path, it is interpreted relative to the installation prefix (Python’s `sys.prefix` for pure-Python packages, `sys.exec_prefix` for packages that contain extension modules).
>
> Each file name in *files* is interpreted relative to the `setup.py` script at the top of the package source distribution.

So the described behavior is simply how `data_files` work.

If you want to include the data files within your package you need to use [`package_data`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data) instead:

```
package_data={'project': ['default_data.json', 'other_datas/default/*.json']}
```

Comment: It is impossible to use package_data if the file is outside the package root (which can happen e.g. if your package is inside 'src', but you want to add in a file outside of it). Isn't there a way to use data_files to go into the package?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/datafolder. It makes it easy to install and use (data files: *.conf, *.ini *.db, ...) by **your package** and **by the user**.

Comment: This package messed up my build and wasted my time. Maybe just a little change here and there could fix the issue, but cannot recommend using it to others.

Answer (score -1):

Change your `MANIFEST.in` to include those `.json`.

It is probably gonna work:

```
recursive-include project/ *.json
```

Comment: There is already that in the manifest, and the files are going, but in  the wrong folder.